# ASP.NET URL encode without ? or variable names

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I'm building a website using ASP.NET webforms and I have a page which accepts a parameter and show content from the database related to that passed parameter. the webpage only has the structure to display the content and it loads the content from tables by querying with the passed parameter.

so far the URL to this page looks like,

> domain.com/view.aspx?id=XX

is there anyway I could achieve the same result using a URL like,

> domain.com/view/xx
>   etc.? anything without question marks and variable name is fine. even better if a meaningful string can be given instead of the parameter value like 'xx' in the above format, like,
>
> domain.com/JohnDoe

where 'John Doe' is the name of the person with the ID 'xx' in the database.(sounds a little ambitious at this point).

How do I achieve this? at least the first portion of the question?

Comment: Take a look at [*Routing*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using asp.net 4.0 or above you can use URL Routing feature, URL Routing works for both ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web forms. Following is the link from where you can get hint on using it.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series